# Cannot construct instance of `com.domain.User` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value

Tags: java, pojo, jsonnode

I have a controller that accepts `ObjectNode` as `@RequestBody`.

That `ObjectNode` represents `json` with some user data

```
{
    "given_name":"ana",
    "family_name": "fabry",
    "email": "fabry@gmail.com",
    "password": "mypass",
    "gender": "FEMALE"
}
```

**Controller.java**

```
@PostMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public JsonNode createUser(@RequestBody ObjectNode user){
        return userService.addUser(user);
 }
```

I want to get user as `ObjectNode` convert it to Java `POJO` save it to database and again return it as `JsonNode`.

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final UserMapper userMapper;

    @Override
    public JsonNode addUser(@RequestBody ObjectNode user) {
        try {
            return userMapper.fromJson(user)
                    .map(r -> {
                        final User created = userRepository.save(r);
                        return created;
                    })
                    .map(userMapper::toJson)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Unable to find user"));
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            throw re;
        }
    }
```

To convert `ObjectNode` to `POJO`

I did this in my `UserMapper` class:

```
public Optional<User> fromJson(ObjectNode jsonUser) {
  User user = objectMapper.treeToValue(jsonUser, User.class);
}
```

Also, to write object to `JsonNode` I did this:

```
public JsonNode toJson(User user) {
        ObjectNode node = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
        node.put("email", user.email);
        node.put("password", user.password);
        node.put("firstName", user.firstName);
        node.put("lastName", user.firstName);
        node.put("gender", user.gender.value);
        node.put("registrationTime", user.registrationTime.toString());
        return node;
}
```

**User.java**

```
@Document(collection = "user")
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    public final String email;
    @JsonProperty("password")
    public final String password;
    @JsonProperty("firstName")
    public final String firstName;
    @JsonProperty("lastName")
    public final String lastName;
    @JsonProperty("gender")
    public final Gender gender;
    @JsonProperty("registrationTime")
    public final Instant registrationTime;

    public static User createUser(
            String email,
            String password,
            String firstName,
            String lastName,
            Gender gender,
            Instant registrationTime){
        return new User(email, password, firstName, lastName, gender, registrationTime);
    }
}
```

When I run my application, this is the error I am receiving:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.domain.User` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

I have read about the error, and it seems this error occurs because Jackson library doesn't know how to create a model which doesn't have an empty constructor and the model contains a constructor with parameters which I annotated its parameters with `@JsonProperty("fieldName")`. But even after applying `@JsonProperty("fieldName")` I am still getting the same error.

I have defined ObjecatMapper as Bean

```
    @Bean
    ObjectMapper getObjectMapper(){
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Jackson needs either a creator method or a no-args constuctor. Since you are using Lombok, you may not be able to annotate the all-args constructor with Jackson annotaition. Can you try with a no-args constructor?

Comment: I am using  immutable class, this is why I can't apply no-args constructor

Comment: If you cannot add a no-args constructor, then add the all-args constructor by hand and annotate it with `@JsonCreator`.

Comment: I annotated my fields with `@JsonProperty` isn't that kinda same?

Comment: No, it is unrelated. The issue here is creating an instance of the class. `@JsonProperty` is used only afterwards.

Comment: I have tried but still getting same error

Comment: I think you use use @Builder
AllArgsConstructor
NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

would works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could reproduce the exception. Then I added an all-args constructor with each parameter annotated with the right `@JsonProperty`.

```java
@JsonCreator
public User( 
    @JsonProperty("email") String email,
    @JsonProperty("password") String password,
    @JsonProperty("firstName") String firstName,
    @JsonProperty("lastName") String lastName,
    @JsonProperty("gender") String gender,
    @JsonProperty("registrationTime") Instant registrationTime){
            super();
            this.email = email;
            this.password = password;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.gender = gender;
            this.registrationTime = registrationTime;
}
```

Now, it creates the instance, but I get other mapping errors (Unrecognized field "given_name") which you should be able to resolve.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Yes, I did like you now. But I am getting null pointer exception from method `toJson` on this line of code `node.put("registrationTime", user.registrationTime.toString());` do you maybe know how can I handle it?

Comment: That may be because the input doesn't have `registrationTime` in it, so `null` is being to the field. You may give it a default value in the constructor above, if `null` is passed to it.

Comment: So maybe the best is to put it as Optional.

Answer (score 2):

Register Jackson [ParameterNamesModule](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/2.14/parameter-names), which will automatically map JSON attributes to the corresponding constructor attributes and therefore will allow you to use immutable classes.

Comment: How can add this to Bean as I am defining my object mapper as bean see update of my question

Answer (score 1):

The error happened in `scala` due to missing the `name` of keys in the constructor.

I missed specifying the names (example `currency`) in the snippet below - `@JsonProperty("currency")`

For converting `json` to `case-class` using scala and jackson, we can do it in the following way -

Add the jackson dependency in `maven/sbt`. If you are using `sbt`, then add the below entry in `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.12.5"
```

Define the case class -

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.{JsonCreator, JsonProperty}

import java.util.Currency

@JsonCreator
case class TopUp (
                   @JsonProperty("cardId") cardId : Long,
                   @JsonProperty("amount") amount : BigDecimal,
                   @JsonProperty("currency") currency: Currency
                 )
object TopUp  {


}
```

In the `main` method -

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import models.oyster.mappers.request.TopUp

object App {
  def main(args : Array[String]): Unit ={
    val tmp =
      """
        |{
        |    "cardId": 718908976540,
        |    "amount": 30.00,
        |    "currency": "GBP"
        |
        |}
        |""".stripMargin

    val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
    val inputParsed = objectMapper.readValue(tmp, classOf[TopUp])
    println("parsed input :: " + inputParsed)

  }

}
```