# Saving json array into postgresql data using spring boot java API

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, postgresql-9.1, spring-data-r2dbc

I have a Json Array in my request object and POJO object, I need to save that jsonarray field into jsonb column in my postgresql table.

```
"productId": "1",
"product":[ 
     {
     "name": "PENCIL",
     "quantity":"5"
     }]
```

I am getting an exception when trying to hit it via postman, getting exception:

Type definition error: [simple type, class io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.Json]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.Json` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information\n at [Source: (io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream); l

Comment: can you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/70143558/175554 and if that does not work can you please put a reproducer to github ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a converter for reading and a converter for writing, thus it will convert between your type and Postgres `io.r2dbc.postgresql.codec.Json`.

```java
@ReadingConverter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JsonToYourTypeConverter implements Converter<Json, YourType > {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    @Override
    public YourType convert(Json json) {
    }
}
```

```java
@WritingConverter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class YourTypeToJsonConverter implements Converter<YourType, Json > {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    @Override
    public Json convert(YourType data) {
    }
}
```

Then register your converters via `R2dbcCustomConversions` bean.

```java
@Bean
public R2dbcCustomConversions r2dbcCustomConversions(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    var dialect = DialectResolver.getDialect(connectionFactory);
    var converters = List.of(
            new JsonToYourTypeConverter(objectMapper),
            new YourTypeToJsonConverter(objectMapper),
    );
    return R2dbcCustomConversions.of(dialect, converters);
}
```